# Data augmentation with bounding boxes

Tags: python, object-detection, yolo, bounding-box, data-augmentation

I want to train an object detection model using YOLO v4. I have a folder containing jpg images with the bounding boxes annotations in a txt file. I don't have much data so I decided to do some data augmentation on my data. I faced the following problems :

1. I have tried Roboflow so I can have directly the bounding boxes in txt files, but the problem is that Roboflow applies randomly data augmentation and sometimes it gives the same picture or applies only a small change.
2. I have tried Albumentations but I had problems with the bounding boxes, I tried the Pascal voc format and it worked but I didn't know how to do it automatically for the whole dataset.

Is there any other solutions or suggestions, I will be grateful.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to worry about data augmentation too much because it has a number of data augmentation techniques that it applies to help improve model performance and generalization.

A few of the data augmentation techniques used by YoloV4 are `CutMix, Blurring, Class label smoothing, Mosaic data augmentation, Self-Adversarial Training`. You can learn more about the different types and impact of various augmentation methods from the YoloV4 paper [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.10934.pdf)

[Here](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/wiki/CFG-Parameters-in-the-%5Bnet%5D-section) is the list of all the data augmentation techniques used in [this](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet) GitHub implementation of YoloV4